# Adding multiple products to WooCommerce cart at once with SKU and URL parameters

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

i found this plugin from Rémi Corson on his website : https://remicorson.com/add-woocommerce-product-to-cart-from-url-using-products-sku/

that uses SKU on add to cart link paramater to work like this : https://storelink.com/?add-to-cart=2312323123 (it can only accept numbers )

my request is i need it to accept multiple SKU like this https://storelink.com/?add-to-cart=2312,2454,5934

and add them to cart.

````
/**
 * Plugin Name: WooCommerce: Add Product to Cart by SKU
 * Plugin URI: http://remicorson.com
 * Description: Just a demo!
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: Remi Corson
 * Author URI: http://remicorson.com/
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}



/**
 * WC Product Add to Cart by SKU class
 */
class WC_Add_to_Cart_by_SKU {

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct() {

        define( 'WC_ADD_TO_CART_BY_SKU_VERSION', '1.0' );
        define( 'WC_ADD_TO_CART_BY_SKU_PATH', untrailingslashit( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) ) );
        define( 'WC_ADD_TO_CART_BY_SKU_PLUGIN_URL', untrailingslashit( plugins_url( basename( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) ), basename( __FILE__ ) ) ) );
    }
    
    /**
     * get_product_id_by_product_sku()
     * 
     * Return product ID from product SKU
     */
    public function get_product_id_by_product_sku( $add_to_cart ) {
    
        global $wpdb;
              
        $product_id = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key='_sku' AND meta_value='%s' LIMIT 1", $add_to_cart ) );
              
        if ( $product_id ) return $product_id;
                
        return $add_to_cart;
    
    }
    
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_product_id', array( new WC_Add_to_Cart_by_SKU(), 'get_product_id_by_product_sku' ) ); ```
````

Comment: _"it can only accept numbers"_ - To apply it also for non-numerical values, see part 2 from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72447306/11987538)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work exactly, but will get you on the right path. You basically create a helper method to create an array and loop through each of the `sku` or post id values.

```
/**
 * WC Product Add to Cart by SKU class
 */
class WC_Add_to_Cart_by_SKU {

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct() {

        define( 'WC_ADD_TO_CART_BY_SKU_VERSION', '1.0' );
        define( 'WC_ADD_TO_CART_BY_SKU_PATH', untrailingslashit( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) ) );
        define( 'WC_ADD_TO_CART_BY_SKU_PLUGIN_URL', untrailingslashit( plugins_url( basename( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) ), basename( __FILE__ ) ) ) );
    }


public function wpso_72553517_add_multiple_products( $add_to_cart ) {
    // If a comma isn't found, send to the method immediately
    if ( ! strpos( ',', $add_to_cart ) ) :
        $this->get_product_id_by_product_sku( $add_to_cart );
    endif;
    
    // Convert the product ids to an array.
    $product_ids = explode( ',', $add_to_cart );
    
    // Loop through each product sku/id 
    foreach ( $product_ids as $product_id ) :
        $this->get_product_id_by_product_sku( $product_id );
    endforeach;
}

public function get_product_id_by_product_sku( $add_to_cart ) {

    global $wpdb;

    $product_id = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key='_sku' AND meta_value='%s' LIMIT 1", $add_to_cart ) );

    if ( $product_id ) {
        return $product_id;
    }

    return $add_to_cart;

   }
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_product_id', array( new WC_Add_to_Cart_by_SKU(), 'wpso_72553517_add_multiple_products' ) );
```

Comment: Hello bro, thanks for your help, i've tested this but it didn't work, it didn't even accept one SKU so maybe there is missed something ?

Comment: Maybe there is something missing - I don't have a way to test it easily. What you can do is `echo '<pre>' . print_r( $add_to_cart ) . '</pre>';` as the first line inside of `wpso_72553517_add_multiple_products` and see what you get.